Why would the card number on my credit card statements change from month to month?
A statement I printed in April shows the last 4 digits of my card on each transaction. I pulled a statement today for the same month, and it shows the last 4 digits of my new card. Shouldn't it stay the card I used?

Just to be absolutely clear: do you mean that transactions that were made with the old number are now being shown as if they were made with the new number?

It sounds like you're saying you printed a statement in April, with statement date of  let's say April 20.   And now you are using their online portal to pull the same statement from April with the same statement date, is that right?

Yes that's correct. I was trying use the statement as a receipt but the 4 digits have been update to the new card # so the merchant wouldn't have that card # on file.

The credit card statement is for the account, and will print with the card number currently associated with the account. The fact that the charge was made to a previous card, which has now been invalidated, doesn't matter for statement purposes; that isn't the actual account number. New charges will not be accepted to the old card, and if any old false charges leak through, you can challenge them and have them removed.
Working as designed.

"The credit card statement is for the account, and will print with the card number currently associated with the account" No. An account has multiple card numbers, specifically in the case of authorized users. They print the last 4 (or 6 in the case of AMEX) to let the account holder sort transactions between authorized users.

An account can have multiple card users. Not all do. The behavior of shared card accounts is outside my experience, so what I've said likely doesn't apply to them.

I second this answer, and add a counter to @user71659's comment, by saying that I am the account holder for a credit card with two authorized users. We each have our own card with only our name on it, but the numbers are identical. The UI for the account only shows the current card number no matter how far back I go. (I did have a compromised card and got a new one at one point).

@keshlam "which ilhas now" --> spelling error?

@user71659 Even if the account has alternate cards, there should be one number that identifies the account itself, and that's what will be shown on the statement. I think this would likely be called something like "primary card".

@Barmar What I think OP is referring to is, for example looking at the closest statement at hand, the transaction detail, which lists date, description, reference number, the last 4 of the card used, and amount. From the last 4 column, I can see which charges were made by which user.

@user71659 I admit I've never had a credit card account with multiple users, so I don't know how this affects statements. When I look at my AmEx statements, the only place where the card number appears is in the header, where it says "Account Ending X-XXXXX", not on individual charges.

Actually, I looked closer. In the detail section, it looks like there's a list for each user, headed by "Card Ending X-XXXXX". In my case it's the same number, but I imagine it would be different for multiple users.

@Barmar Yeah, AmEx always issues different card numbers to authorized users; the statement separation is why. I think Visa and Mastercard require banks do so only on high-tier and travel feature cards, and certainly corporate accounts that can easily have thousands of cards.

Pretty sure I've had long-time recurring payments transferred from a (compromised) old card to a new card, at least with Amex, and payments to the old card definitely get transferred.

Indeed, the last four digits of the original card used for such transactions should definitely be visible. This may be a bug or perhaps an update on their end - I think it could be helpful to reach out to your bank for more reasons as to why it has changed.

What would be the benefit of reaching out to the bank for the reasons? It sounds like the OP is more curious than concerned.

@Sneftel, because if in the future someone steals a card, uses and the transaction gets registered as been made by the new card (and not the stolen one), the bank may not cancel it or reimburse the money.

@osiris If the card number has already changed, then how would the old card be used for a future transaction?

As an bank employee in "Central Banking Systems" department I find it wrong that there is incorrect card number, but it does not surprise me.
There are various ways statements are done and often statements have to be done as soon as possible otherwise some information is lost in time (it could still be available, but stored in historic tables, or available only with additional effort like recovering from tape storage).
Often statements are generated and archived and you cannot generate it again (after some reasonable period), instead it is only available from archive. Movements tend to be split into multiple tables like basic information and details and also split into multiple tables based on source.
After half a year I would expect movement details to still be available in historic tables, but how is it used in statement depends on a lot of things. So it is also possible card number used is no longer readily available.
If you really want to know just contact your bank. This seems like a reasonable request and not the one front-office would know how to answer. At least at the bank I currently work at I would expect it to end on programmer responsible for this statements. We often do not like such questions, but that is not a problem with client but more with responsibilities and knowledge sharing through bank hierarchy.
